# Convert "0.25000%" to double in java

Tags: java, string, double, type-conversion

Please help to convert the string value ("0.25000%") to double value.

0.25000% = 0.0025 (need to get this value as double)

```
String num = "0.25000%";

double d = Double.parseDouble(num);//does not work
```

Comment: Why don't you substring and remove last `%` character? Or you can use `replace`

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
 String num = "0.25000%";
 double d = Double.parseDouble(num.replace("%","")); // remove %
 System.out.println(d);
```

Out put:

```
 0.25
```

For your edit:

You can divide final answer by `100`

```
System.out.println(d/100);
```

Now out put:

```
0.0025
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String num = "0.25000%";
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(num .trim().replace("%","")).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100));//no problem BigDecimal
```

this can convert for decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `%` character and divide by 100

```
String num = "0.25000%";
double d = Double.parseDouble(num.replace("%","")) / 100;
```